# How to check if a button's image = nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to check if one of my UIButton's image is equal to nil. Is there a way to do so? I wasn't sure about `myButton.image` as it's not on Apple's developer Reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently a UIButton has a property called `currentImage` and `currentBackgroundImage`. It will check for the current image (depending on state, for example pressed state or normal state).

Answer (score 1):

Use `- (UIImage *)imageForState:(UIControlState)state`.